# convert strings to symbolic expressions, respecting workspace

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Matlab can convert a string to a symbolic expression, but here I want the string to be interpreted according to values known in the workspace:

```
syms x y
y = x;
sym('x + y')  % depending on version, use "sym(", "str2sym(" or "evalin(symengine,"
ans =
x + y
```

How to code for an output of x + x or 2*x?

Another example:

```
syms x y
y = x;
z = sym('a + y')
```

how to modify the code to give z = a + x?

The basic problem seems to be that sym(string) simply is ignorant to the past (not taking into account what has been defined before) and the future (not declaring its variables as syms - how could it?)

I think a simple expression parser could do it: check if a variable in the string exists in the workspace, and declare it as symbolic if not.

Comment: `eval`, `subs`, and other related functions do things along these lines, but your question is pretty unclear - what do you *expect* the result to be for a specific example?

Comment: Why are you using sym and strings in the first place? If the values that you want to use are already in the workspace, why don't you directly use `x+y`?

Comment: The expected result should be clear from the last line: I want to modify the code that the result is equivalent to 2x.

Sym and strings are needed because of a special problem setup.
Some of he equations are built from other equations, some are specified as strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
function y = str2syms(symstr)
%STR2SYMS evaluates symstr where symstr is a string 
% representing a symbolic expression.
% Additionally to str2sym, str2syms declares unknown variables
% as symbolic in the caller workspace.
%
% Example:
% syms x y
% y = x;
% z = str2syms('a + y')
% creating symbolic variable a
% z =
% a + x

% very simple tokenizer to find variables
vars = strread(symstr,'%s','delimiter',',:;= ()^*/+-.0123456789@');
% collect all known variables
W = evalin('caller','whos'); %or 'base'
for i = 1:numel(vars)
    v = vars{i};
    if ~isempty(v)
        % create symbolic variable if not already known
        if ~ismember(v,[W(:).name]) & ~exist(v)
        %if ~exist(v)
            disp(['creating symbolic variable ', v])
            assignin('caller', v, sym(v));
        end
    end
end
% convert (single) = to ==
ieq = strfind(symstr,'=');
if ieq
    symstr = [symstr(1:ieq),'=',symstr(ieq+1:end)];
end
% evaluate
y = evalin('caller', symstr);
```

Uploaded to file exchange https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/67519-str2syms-symstr-